# Getting input text back out of MessageDigest

Tags: java, message-digest

There are many people here on SO suggesting different approaches to the problem that I am having, but non of them seem to work for me. I am currently testing a timestamp server and (among other things, I am sending the server a message) and I need to read that the message exists in the answer. So I am creating a request and preparing it:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
String s = "Trolololoooo";
DigestInputStream stream = new DigestInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF-8")), digest)
byte[] digest2 = stream.getMessageDigest().digest();

// timestamp stuff is all org.bouncycastle.tsp.*
TimeStampRequestGenerator timeStampRequestGenerator = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
timeStampRequestGenerator.setReqPolicy(String.valueOf(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.13762.3")));
TimeStampRequest timeStampRequest = timeStampRequestGenerator.generate(TSPAlgorithms.SHA1, digest2, BigInteger.valueOf(666));
byte request[] = timeStampRequest.getEncoded();
```

... skipped the sending part, ok got the answer

```
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
TimeStampResp resp = TimeStampResp.getInstance(new ASN1InputStream(in).readObject());
TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(resp);
response.validate(timeStampRequest);
```

Now, from the response, I can successfully read the byte stream like:

```
byte[] messageImprintDigest1 = response.getTimeStampToken().getTimeStampInfo().getMessageImprintDigest();

for( byte b : messageImprintDigest1) System.out.print(b);
```

Will output: *-3857-93-189410775135085-65-17-1079624-112-81-4079*

Anyway, I have been blindly trying all the suggestion that I have found, that would translate back to "Trolololoooo", but no success. Some (not limited to) things I have tried:

```
    String s1 = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(messageImprintDigest1);
    String s2 = new String(Hex.decodeHex(s1.toCharArray()), "UTF-8");
    // how could that help me..? but nothing to lose here.
    String s3 = Hex.encodeHexString(messageImprintDigest1);

    String convert = convert(s1);
//    String convert1 = convert(s2);
//    String convert2 = convert(s3);

    int len = s1.length();
    byte[] cStr = new byte[len/2];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i+=2) {
        cStr[i/2] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(i, i+2), 16);
    }
    CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
    ByteBuffer wrap = ByteBuffer.wrap(cStr);
    CharBuffer decode = decoder.decode(wrap);

    CharBuffer cb = decoder.decode( ByteBuffer.wrap( cStr ));
    String s4 = cb.toString();
```

...

```
public static String convert(String hex){
    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(hex.length()/2);
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
        buff.put((byte)Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i, i+2), 16));
    }
    buff.rewind();
    Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    CharBuffer cb = cs.decode(buff);
    return  cb.toString();
}
```

Anyway, it is probably some obvious stuff I am missing, like that the messageImprintDigest1 doesn't look like a hex string at all (pardon me, I studied geology in university).. This stuff is all very new to me, so it is hard to argue with the compiler or some other stuff out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the original text back from a message digest. It's a one-way process.

Comment: Just to be sure: _The messageImprint MUST have the same value as the similar field in
TimeStampReq, provided that the size of the hash value matches the
expected size of the hash algorithm identified in hashAlgorithm._ [Ref](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt) (page 8) means just comparing the hashes?

Comment: I suggest you make up your mind what this question is really about. It's already had one incorrect title. If you're asking how to implement RFC 3161 you should have said so up front.

Comment: I don't have to implement, but I have to test the implementation in the near future and as all this CA and PKI etc stuff is very new to me, I was just playing around with it a little. Anyway, if it is not possible to convert the messagedigest back, then this answers this specific question.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this simple solution?

```
byte[] b = "Trolololoooo".getBytes();
String s = new String(b);       
System.out.println(s);
```

will output Trolololoooo.

Comment: It's a simple solution all right, but not to this question. You don't appear to have even read it.